# 400 (Bad Request) Error: Calling a WCF .net service from backbone model's fetch infrastrucure

Tags: .net, wcf, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to set up my first Backbone Model that implements RESTful WCF services.  Here is what I have so far:  My router creates the User Model and I simply want to perform a fetch().  I created a dummy webservice just to try and get it going before I right my actual WS code.

EDIT:  I believe this is a problem with my web.config, not sure what I need

MY ROUTER:

```
define([
    'backbone', 
    'dashboard',
    'models/UserModel'
], 
function(Backbone, Dashboard, UserModel) {
    var homeRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize : function() {
            Backbone.history.start();           
        },

        routes : {
            '' : 'home',
            'docs': 'docs'

        },

        'home' : function() {

            var user = new UserModel({userId: 'cjestes'});
            user.fetch();

        },

        'docs' : function() {
            //load docs page

        }

    });

    return new homeRouter();
});
```

My MODEL:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone'
], 
function($, Backbone) {
    //Docs Metro View
    var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        userId: " ",

        url:  "services/User.svc/GetUserInformation",

        initialize: function () {

            this.userId = this.get("id");

        }

    });

    // Return the Docs Model
    return userModel;
});
```

MY SVC:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Specialized;


namespace Mri.Dashboard.services
{

    public class User : IUser
    {
        public string GetUserInformation()
        {
            return "hello";

        }
    }
}
```

MY INTERFACE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Mri.Dashboard.services
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IUser" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUser
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetUserInformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears that you have not annotated your service contract with [WebGet] attribute! In order to use REST wcf, you need to map the OperationContract to a URI via UriTemplate="GetUserInformation" something like this: [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="GetUserInformation")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this I ended up using a .svc/config - less WCF implmentation.  I started with this template which lays out everything you need to do it get REST WCF up and running.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd

I was able to use this template in conjunction with the backbone model's built in sync, it is very easy to do and use.